# Message not Received when setting Source and Destination Port

Tags: java, smslib

Using SMSLib 3.5.4 i am able to receive and send messages to the device.

But the message is not reaching the device when both source and destination port is set to the outbound message. whereas when i do not set any source and destination port it works fine i.e the message is reaches the device.

Code used is below

`OutboundMessage lmsg = new OutboundMessage(no, messageTxt);
lmsg.setSrcPort(50000);
lmsg.setDstPort(50000);
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(lmsg);`

No exception being thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an app on the device which processes messages on that port ?

Comment: Yes, when an app is listening on the particular port message is read by it, but when there is no app listening on the particular port, shouldn't it be read by default messaging app on the device?

Comment: No, as far as i know, the message is lost in that case. But that may depend on the System.